# Не могу загрузить Ubuntu после расширения диска

Tags: linux, windows-7, boot

После того как добавил новый том путем расширения существующего, при попытке загрузится с Ubuntu получаю ошибку типа `grub rescue: no such partition`, причем сам раздел на котором стоит Ubuntu не изменялся/удалялся. Как исправить?

[image: разделы диска]

Comment: Так вы добавляли новый раздел или расширяли. И если расширяли, то какое пространство при этом использовалось. И какой из разделов расширяли. и не мог ли он задеть собой область данных на которой лежит linux раздел. Вообще лучше загрузится с какого нибудь установочного linux диска и посмотреть как он видит разделы, то что показывает винда особо ни о чем не говорит так как она не показывает важные параметры разделов, такие как их тип.

Comment: Нужно восстановить Grub. Загрузиться live-cd и провести процесс восстановления.

Comment: Создавал новый раздел способом сжатия диска D

Answer (score 0):

1. Загружаетесь с Live флешки
2. Заходите в терминал и смотрите таблицу разделов `sudo fdisk -l`
3. Смотрите напротив которого указана ваша система и подключаете этот раздел в /mnt `sudo mount /dev/ваш_раздел /mnt`
4. Восстанавливаем grub `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`